# slideshow flicker problem

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i'm trying to make a flash-like animation w indipendent transitions of text and bg-images.

avail at http://79.99.2.133/slide/slide.html

In FF (OSX), there's a flickering between the images, what am i doing wrong?

with an inserted alert() (avail at http://79.99.2.133/slide/slide2.html) the flicker is gone.

*add:*
and IE8 renders text (png-alpha) ugly when fading in/out. Any way out of it?

reagards,
//t

Comment: Are you sure it's not just the system you're running it on?? It runs fine on FF @ OSX here.

Comment: @rudi, thanks. For me on FF4, the flickering starts after 10 secs.

Comment: Did you try preloading the images?

Comment: @user247245, update your browser as well. Links to your code are gone now but if the upgrade doesn't help you could look at optimising your code to only include the necessary animation functions. That will at least give you more debugging power as well.